# how to manage Timer with Interval

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to send a report to every month first day at 6am. Please help for the logic for this for time interval for window service, please suggest

```
private System.Timers.Timer svcTimerForSendEmailSrvc = null;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
            svcTimerForSendEmailSrvc = new System.Timers.Timer();
            svcTimerForSendEmailSrvc.Enabled = true;
            svcTimerForSendEmailSrvc.Interval = //here not getting time every month 1st date 6am mail should send
            svcTimerForSendEmailSrvc.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(svcTimerForSendEmailSrvc_Elapsed);
            svcTimerForSendEmailSrvc.Start();
    }

void svcTimerForSendEmailSrvc_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        SendReportEverymonth1day();
    }
```

Example i need send email to every month 1 6am.

like `1 jan 2022 next mail 1 feb 2022 next....1 dec 2022`

Comment: Either use [Windows Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) or a Scheduling Framework. A simple Timer won't make you happy.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion, can you share sample code. @Fildor

Comment: One more suggestion, actually this is my mvc application, i thought window service will do my job but can we do this job from mvc application. @Filder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Third-party solutions such as [FluentScheduler](https://fluentscheduler.github.io/) or [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) can be used to schedule code to run on a specific interval, e.g.:

```
Schedule<MyComplexJob>().ToRunNow().AndEvery(1).Months().OnTheFirst(DayOfWeek.Monday).At(3, 0);
```

A timer cannot.

Another option, as suggested by @Fildor, is to use the Task Scheduler in Windows to start a program that runs your code on a given schedule like for example once a month.

Comment: The above your single line code which thirday-party solutions you have used, can we do this same using MVC application without writing window service.?

Comment: Yes, if you choose to use FluentScheduler you don't need to use the task scheduler. It's one way or the other, not both.

Comment: this example is not help for me to implement the logic, Schedule<MyComplexJob>().ToRunNow().AndEvery(1).Months().OnTheFirst(DayOfWeek.Monday).At(3, 0); not getting to start, can you please more detail. @mm8

Comment: I provided a link to the official docs. Please refer to it for more information about FluentScheduler. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: ok thanks i will update your answer. @mm8

Comment: Can we do like this also na: app.setting code: <add key="MonthlyReportServiceFirstSayTime" value="2022-01-01 06:00 AM" />
Windows code
string strWPRServiceRunTime = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MonthlyReportServiceFirstSayTime"];
DateTime serviceRunTime = Convert.ToDateTime(strWPRServiceRunTime);
DateTime date =DateTime.Now();
var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
if ((DateTime.Now.Hour == serviceRunTime.Hour && DateTime.Now.Minute == serviceRunTime.Minute) && (serviceRunTime.date == firstDayOfMonth.date)).
@mm8